# How to check whether microphone boost is enable using C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Just wonder whether it's possible to check whether microphone boost is enable and disable it using C#

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a audio control library for that. Check out [AudioLib](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11695/Audio-Library-Part-I-Windows-Mixer-Control), which has specific mixer, boost, etc. controls for audio input/output devices.